# Memory not being released after killing the GLSurfaceView

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, glsurfaceview

I have observed from the Android Studio Profiler that the 'Graphics' memory is not reducing even after releasing the GLSurfaceView.

My scenario is like this - when the activity is launched I show a simple View with a button. On clicking the button, it will show a GLSurfaceView that draws a single triangle. When I do a tap on screen, it will destroy the GLSurfaceView and come back to the Simple View (with only button).

[image]